# How can I make a core link field have the option to open in a new tab?

Tags: 10

I have created a block type with some fields, but then I created a link type for some buttons and I need this link type field to have the option to open in a new tab when the content is uploaded.

Is there a way to implement it, a module? I hope you can help me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question completely, but you can probably use the [Link Attributes widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/link_attributes) module.

> ### Overview
>
> Link attributes widget provides an additional widget for the link
> field found in Drupal core.
>
> The widget allows users to set attributes on their link.
>
> In addition the module alters the default menu link content link field
> to use this widget, allowing menu links to have attributes too
>
> ### Features
>
> Supported attributes include
>
> - id
> - class
> - name
> - target
> - rel
> - accesskey
> - aria-label (since 8.x-1.3)
> - title (since 8.x-1.7)
> - Linkit support (since 2.1.0) - via a submodule

If that doesn't help, its source code can definitely guide you to a custom solution.